# Can the Shillelagh cantrip be active on two clubs at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons, druid, cantrips

My Druid uses two clubs. Can I have the *shillelagh* cantrip active on both clubs at once?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### No, *shillelagh* can only be active on one weapon at a time.

The [*shillelagh*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shillelagh) spell description says:

> The wood of **a** club or quarterstaff you are holding is imbued with nature's power. [...] **The spell ends if you cast it again** or if you let go of the weapon. (emphasis mine)

It says the wood of *a* club or quarterstaff, which is only one. At the end of the spell description, it says this spell ends if you cast it again. So sadly, no you can’t dual-wield 1d8+Wis weapons at 1st level with no feats.

Comment: Although not mentioned as a possibility, would it be worthwhile to discuss if the Sorcerer's Twinned metamagic accomplishes this?

Comment: @RallozarX Unfortunately it does not. Twinned Spell Metamagic only works on spells that target "one **creature**"

Comment: If your DM wants to achieve this narratively they could house-rule to let you snap a quaterstaff in half after casting _shillelagh_ – as the somatic component of the spell, as an interaction with an object, or over the head of an enemy as your attack on the first round – to make two (improvised) clubs you are still holding, and repair it afterwards with _mending_.